# Páginas em branco - wamp server

Tags: php, html, css, aplicação-web, wamp

Olá! Antes de ontem o meu Wamp Server começou a dar um bug estranho em que todas as páginas do projeto, inclusive o phpmyadmin, ficaram em branco. Sem erro, só branco.
O que eu tentei pra ver se resolvia:

- reiniciar os serviços;
- reiniciar o pc;
- apagar a db;
- retirar meus arquivos de projeto da pasta www;
- limpar cache do navegador;
- reinstalar o wamp;
- mudar a porta do wamp;
- verificar a porta 80 pelo telnet;

Por fim, resolveu-se comigo apenas reiniciando o Wi-fi do meu Notebook. PORÉM, o problema voltou a acontecer agora e já repeti todos os processos descritos acima, além de reiniciar o wi-fi em meu Notebook e também reiniciar o modem (vai que...). Ainda não voltou, então isso deve ser algo mais sério. Alguma ideia?[image]

ERRORLOG APACHE: https://pastebin.com/6EBhvGPP

Comment: Isso pode ser alguma outra aplicação usando a porta 80. Um exemplo é o Skype, tenta trocar a porta do Apache do Wamp server e vê se funciona na nova porta.

Comment: Usei o telnet pra ver se a porta estava ocupada, e nada...

Comment: Mudei a porta por via das dúvidas e ainda nada...

Comment: Posta o log do Apache, pra ver se existe alguma pista do problema lá.

Comment: Ta aí https://pastebin.com/6EBhvGPP